# Recurrent posting about «Matrix polynomials» and so on

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, moderation

MO is currently being the focus of what I guess to be a single particular individual [R.T.Man](https://mathoverflow.net/users/78479/r-t-man) sporting multiple unregistered users identity (like [Eskand](https://mathoverflow.net/users/89148/eskand) or [H.night](https://mathoverflow.net/users/89001/h-night)). S/he's asking multiple *very similar and basic* questions in the topic of «matrix polynomial» and other related topological issues (like [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230371) but other very similar questions seem to appear and disappear shortly afterwards on a regular basis). I'm *fed up* voting to close and seeing again and again the same questions popping up. I'm sure moderators noticed that little game, as Todd closed single-handedly at least one post ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233709)).

Can something be done in terms of IP filtering or is the user abusing the system by vpn-ing his/her entry here?

More generally, what can the community do about such behavior? What should be the right route to convince him/her of stopping being such a pain in the good-will of others?

Comment: This user (in various incarnations) has been told repeatedly, and there's no point that I can see in repeating the messages. My plan now is to close and delete on sight, no questions asked. So please just flag for moderator attention. If this persists, then I think we moderators would consider stronger measures.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I'll do what you suggest.

Comment: Down-voting is also important (in addition to voting to close). It might seem pointless on a individual question basis for a 1 point account, but it costs nothing on a question, makes the question disappear from the frontpage, and most importantly these signals are picked up and feed into automatic and semi-automatic measures.

Comment: A different flavour of question, but still betraying signs of not getting the message: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/237793/what-will-draw-a-shape-for-l-left-lambda-in-mathbbcs-4-lambda